# LISP key-value binding store and look up

Tags: lisp, key-value

I am learning LISP, just want to ask what the best option is to store a key-value pair in a LISP program.

For the key-value pair I mentioned, I want to use it like Map Collection in JAVA: I want to store the key with value, and can look up value by key.

for example: if I have a string `"apple"` match with `"fruit"`, I want to be able to store this pair if it does not exist, and can query for the value associate with `"apple"`, which is fruit.

any recommendation or code sample will be greatly helpful. thank you in advance

Comment: use hash-tables, and for string keys you also need to specify `EQUAL` as the test argument (default is `EQL`, which doesn't work on strings: think Java's `==` and `equals()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which Lisp you're learning (Scheme, Common Lisp, etc) So I'm going to guess Common Lisp. If I am incorrect please comment and I will edit accordingly.

In Lisp such a thing is called an association list. It is very commonly used and so there are a few convenience functions to make it possible. At its core though, it's really nothing more than a list of pairs `((key . value) ... )`.

I would recommend checking out [Carnegie Melon's explanation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node153.html), it will give you a brief overview of functions like `assoc` and `alist-cons` which make working with association lists easy. I found it very helpful.

The problem with association lists is that while they have constant time insertion, deletion and lookup are both *O(n)*. Therefore if speed is a big concern, you'll want to turn to actual hash tables.

The [Common Lisp Cook book](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/hashes.html) has a good explanation for these. They rely on actual arrays (sometimes called vectors) which allow constant time random access. Unlike association lists, these do offer *O(1)* lookup. However they aren't as easy to use as association lists because, well, Lisp is good at lists in general.

Note: For Scheme most of these functions should be provided with the SRFI 1 and 69 extensions, if your compiler doesn't provide it by default.

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp you can use association lists.

See the Common Lisp Hyperspec about [association lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_aba.htm) and on the function [ASSOC](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm)

For anything more complex and faster, Common Lisp provides [hash tables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/18_.htm).

Answer (score 0):

To make the comparison fair, `Map` in Java is an interface. It has various implementations, which are so different they may not offer you the same complexity at read/write/delete operations. Some may be implemented as linked lists, others may be binary tries etc.

`Map` in Java *only* defines the way you access the data, but it doesn't define how data is stored.

Lisps, well, if you think about CLOS, don't have a concept of the interface, this is because CLOS supports multiple inheritance. There's no adequate analogue to Java's `Map` simply because there's no concept of accessing collections in this way and no concept of interfaces, as they exist in Java.

There are several standard implementations of `Map` in Java. One is the `HashMap` (`Hashtable` is very similar to it). This is very similar to `hash-table` class in Common Lisp. There's also `LinkedHashMap` in Java, which is very similar to association list in Lisp. A bare-bones Lisp doesn't provide red-black tree maps and there's not standardized behaviour with regards to threads - you would need to read the documentation regarding particular implementation, but you can find a lot of good implementations of various data structures here: http://www.cliki.net/Data%20structure .